# SIRD Router not resolving a route

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have created a `SIRD` Router. But it is not resolving my route. What is the mistake in the following code?

SIRD Router file UserRouter.scala in package WSRouters.User

```
package WSRouters.User

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._
import controllers.UserController

class UserRouter @Inject()(controller:UserController) extends SimpleRouter {

  override def routes:Routes = {
    case GET(p"users/add") => {
      println(s"add user request");
      controller.addUser();
    }
  }
}
```

routes.conf

```
#using SIRD to handle user related web services
->      /users                      WSRouters.User.UserRouter
```

controller

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import javax.inject._

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class UserController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc){

  def addUser = Action.async{ implicit request => Future{Ok("hello from the User controller")}}
}
```

when I enter the path `http://localhost:9000/users/add`, I get the following error. The routes tried doesn't even have my router.

```
Action Not Found

For request 'GET /users/add'
These routes have been tried, in this order:

1  GET / controllers.HomeController.index

2  GET / homecontrollers.HomeController.index

3  GET / countcontrollers.CountController.count

4  GET / messagecontrollers.AsyncController.message

5  GET /assets/$file<.+>  controllers.Assets.versioned(path:String = "/public", file:Asset)
```

Do I need to do some configuration so that Play uses my router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake was that the code in router should be `case GET(p"/add")` instead of `case GET(p"users/add")` because **`/user` is already mapped to `UserRouter`** by following line in *routes* file:

```
->      /users                      WSRouters.User.UserRouter
```

My original code, `case GET(p"users/add")` would resolve `http://localhost:9000/users/users/add`.

Comment: Thanks. I faced the same issue and your answer helped me.